# PHP SESSION cookie_samesite Strict: redirect from PayPal logs the customer out and starts a new session, how to keep it on the same page?

Tags: php

How to maintain the session for a user redirect after successful payment?
While still using: `ini_set('session.cookie_samesite', 'strict');`

Problem: Redirect from PayPal logs the customer out and starts a new session.

The script redirects a user after the payment to thankyou.php
with `$site='thankyou';`

so i tried in header.php:

```
if($site!='thankyou'){
ini_set('session.cookie_httponly', 1 );
ini_set('session.cookie_secure', '1');
ini_set('session.cookie_samesite', 'strict');
ini_set("session.use_strict_mode", true);
session_start();
}

if($site=='thankyou'){
ini_set('session.cookie_httponly', 1 );
ini_set('session.cookie_secure', '1');
ini_set('session.cookie_samesite', 'lax');
ini_set("session.use_strict_mode", true);
session_start();
}
```

but, maybe it makes no sense, the session was set before already, set to "strict". Even if i set it to 'none', will result in the log out / new session.

EDIT: i solved it (half) by using the above code +

```
session_start();
**session_regenerate_id ();**
```

At the page, the step right before the user will visit the PayPal checkout site. It will set the cookie new and change the "samesite" to "lax". Not perfect because "strict" had his reasons.

Comment: So you can handle this 2 ways, one way would be separate payment processing and thank you page and the other way would be use a unique identifier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
session_start();
**session_regenerate_id ();**
```

At the page, the step right before the user will visit the PayPal checkout site. It will set the cookie new and change the "samesite" to "lax". Not perfect because "strict" had his reasons.